# Py3 I print("text", variable, "text") it outputs correctly but when I set as a variable instead of print it adds multiple ( ' , ') into the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is likely a simple question but for some reason I am stuck on trying to figure this out.

Here is the sample code that is working correctly when using print():

```
animal = "cat"
food = "bread"
day = "Monday"
print("The", animal, "ate", food, "on", day)
```

It has the desired output of:

```
The cat ate bread on Monday
```

But, when I set it as a variable:

```
animal = "cat"
food = "bread"
day = "Monday"
sentence = ("The", animal, "ate", food, "on", day)
print(sentence)
```

It outputs as:

```
('The', 'cat', 'ate', 'bread', 'on', 'Monday')
```

I tried to convert to string, as well as text replace with no luck. Much appreciate the help!

Comment: use `" ".join(sentence)`

Comment: Or `print(*sentence)`.  One tuple parameter is not at all equivalent to six separate parameters.

Comment: Thanks guys, works perfect now. Didn't consider joining. Awesome

Comment: @JasonWaltz the variable "sentence"  has become a data structure called "tuple", type(sentence) to verify this, you can read more about tuple in the python docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `print("The", animal, "ate", food, "on", day)`, you are calling the built-in Python3 `print()` function. By default, this function adds spaces in between each of the parameters provided to it.

On the other hand, when you call `sentence = ("The", animal, "ate", food, "on", day)`, you are actually creating a data structure called a `tuple` (it's similar to a list). See more info on this in the [Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

To place all of the elements from the tuple into a string, you can use `" ".join(sentence)`. This will take the elements of the tuple and concatenate them, separating each element by the provided string (in this case, a space character).

Note that you can separate the elements by any string that you like using `join()`! For example, `"||".join( ("What", "a", "nice", "day!") )` will concatenate the tuple into the string `What||a||nice||day!`.

Comment: Awesome answer, you helped me a ton to understand what was going on here. Many thanks

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making `sentence` like this - `sentence = ("The " + animal + " ate " + food + " on " + day)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "**,**" try using "**+**" for concatenation